# HTML, CSS, JS in separate area not affecting entire website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to put up tutorials on my website. In order for the user to see some examples I want to output the code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) plus the result.

So my markup for a the code box, including a little example, looks like the following:

```
<div class="code-box">
    <code class="code-section lang-html">
        <!-- Example HTML code -->
        <div> <span>This</span> is an example </div>
    </code>
    <code class="code-section lang-css">
        /* Example CSS code */
        div{
            font-size: 120%;
        }
        div span{
            font-size: 130%;
        }
    </code>
   <code class="code-section lang-js">
       /* Example jQuery code */
       $("div").hover(function(){
           $(this).find("span").css("fontSize", "140%");
       }, function(){
           $(this).find("span").css("fontSize", "130%");
       });
    </code>
   <code class="code-section lang-result">
       <!-- Example result -->
   </code>
</div>
```

Via JavaScript/jQuery I escape necessary characters like "<" that are inside the code tags, so that the actual code is printed as text, and not evaluated as eg HTML.

No problems so far.
My problem arises when it comes to the "result" part, where I actually want the written code to be evaluated as code. So far I got it to work with jQuery:
Unescaping the HTML characters, putting the css stuff inside a  tag, and the JS inside a  tag. The problem now being that the "new" Css and JS will also apply to the rest of the website <-- definitely not what I want. But whats the solution?

I found an article about "scoped css":
Putting your css inside a   tag will make the css apply to only the parent and its children elements. But support is low and this would only help the CSS, not the JS.
Givng my example code an id or class is simple, but not something desirable for each tutorial I wanna put up there, neither for writing nor for reading.

I would need to wrap that tutorial-code in a bubble, separated from my website's code. Kind of like an iframe or such. I would really appreciate any ideas or comments on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you are tryingf to achieve [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/0c1np9uL/1/).

```
var parent = $(".code-box.example-1"),
    parentC = parent.attr("class").match(/example-\d+/),
    htmlSnip = parent.find(".lang-html > pre").text().replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">"),
    cssSnip = parent.find(".lang-css > pre").html().replace(/(\/\*.*\*\/\n)|(^\s*)/gm, "").replace(/^([^{\n]+)(?={$)/gm, "." + parentC + " .lang-result " + "$1"),
    jsSnip = parent.find(".lang-js > pre").html().replace(/(\/\*.*\*\/\n)|(^\s*)/gm, "").replace(/(\$\(")([^"]+)("\))/gm, "$1." + parentC + " .lang-result " + "$2 $3");

parent.find(".lang-result").html(htmlSnip).prepend("<style>" + cssSnip + "</style>" + "<script>" + jsSnip + "<\/script>");
```

If this is what you are looking for and you require additiional information, let me know. The key is to add a class per code example you are using, here `.example-1`.

For some regex explanations, I refer you to [regex101](https://regex101.com). It's a great tool with a very good explanation of all code in the right window. As you may know, you can use RegEx to match, but also to substitute. In the tool, at the bottom of the window, there's "Substitution". Click on it, to open the window. The Regex at the top of the page will evaluate the "Test string", and substitute that string with your input in "Substitution". The result is in the bottom most field.

**CSS substitution**:
First, let's remove the CSS comment AND all spatial characters that might be in our way (removing means "replace by an empty string") - example: https://regex101.com/r/cL0hL3/2

The result will be something like this:

```
div{
font-size: 120%;
}
div span{
font-size: 130%;
}
```

But we want to make this style more specific. We want it to only apply to the div that's inside `.lang-result` which, in turn, is part of the parent container `.example-1`. Therefore we need to add some things to the CSS. A useful thing to use is the dollar sign `$1` which in substitution will return the captured group (which in regex is in parentheses). `$1` returns the first captured group, `$2` the second one and so on. Here's an example: https://regex101.com/r/cL0hL3/3. The result will then look how we want:

```
.parent-class .lang-result div{
font-size: 120%;
}
.parent-class .lang-result div span{
font-size: 130%;
}
```

**JS substitution**: the first part is identical to the CSS regex: remove the comment (doesn't work with `//` comments only with `/*...*/`). That will lead to:

```
$("div").hover(function(){
$(this).find("span").css("fontSize", "140%");
}, function(){
$(this).find("span").css("fontSize", "130%");
});
```

Then we'll have to change the base selector (the div) the only the div in our result (smilar to what we did in the case for CSS). This is a good time to show what capturing groups do (you can do this without using three groups, but it's a good way to illustrate its possibilities:

We replace this

```
(\$\(")([^"]+)("\))
```

with this

```
$1.parent-class $2$3
```

It's crucial to see how `$1` is the first group `(\$\(")` (literally `$("`, `$2` is whichever selector was already there, and `$3` is literally `")`. Put that all together, and you have a new jQuery object.

See it in action here. https://regex101.com/r/cL0hL3/4

Again there are many other ways to do that in regex, probably more efficient as well, but it's a good showcase. I didn't go into too much detail, but you can take the right window of the website as an explanation for what your regular expression does.

---

If you want to apply this to multiple elements without manually added classes, you can do it like so: http://jsfiddle.net/0c1np9uL/2/

```
$(".code-box").each(function () {
    var parent = $(this);
    parent.addClass("example-" + parent.index());

    var parentC = parent.attr("class").match(/example-\d+/),
        htmlSnip = parent.find(".lang-html > pre").text().replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">"),
        cssSnip = parent.find(".lang-css > pre").html().replace(/(\/\*.*\*\/\n)|(^\s*)/gm, "").replace(/^([^{\n]+)(?={$)/gm, "." + parentC + " .lang-result " + "$1"),
        jsSnip = parent.find(".lang-js > pre").html().replace(/(\/\*.*\*\/\n)|(^\s*)/gm, "").replace(/(\$\(")([^"]+)("\))/gm, "$1." + parentC + " .lang-result " + "$2 $3");

    parent.find(".lang-result").html(htmlSnip).prepend("<style>" + cssSnip + "</style>" + "<script>" + jsSnip + "<\/script>");
});
```

Comment: I'm so sorry I know nothing about regular expression. Could you explain or add some comments on what going on for each re in your code? Once I know that I'll be able to apply it to my case.

Comment: @DeadManWalker See my edit. If it helped, please vote it up. If it fixed your problem or answered your question, check the mark to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, very nice I appreciate that. So you've done exactly what I thought. Although this is the best solution so far, can you imagine a way that would not require me to add an id or different class to every tutorial-parent-div?

Comment: @DeadManWalker In a loop you can add a unique class per element in jQuery and then apply the function, like so: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0c1np9uL/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific with your selections, instead of having `$("div")` use `$("#result div")`, also a nice thing you can do with jQuery instead of wraping it, you can use `if` so: `if($("#result div").attr("on") == "on") {//do stuff}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textarea`s to display your code. As for the "results" section, an iframe is probably your best bet.

```css
.code{
    border:0;
    resize: none;
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="code">
        <!-- Example HTML code -->
        <div> <span>This</span> is an example </div>
</textarea><br>

<textarea class="code">
        /* Example CSS code */
        div{
            font-size: 120%;
        }
        div span{
            font-size: 130%;
        }
</textarea><br>

<textarea class="code">
       /* Example jQuery code */
       $("div").hover(function(){
           $(this).find("span").css("fontSize", "140%");
       }, function(){
           $(this).find("span").css("fontSize", "130%");
       });
</textarea>
```

Comment: [Try avoid using XMP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp).

Comment: @BramVanroy yeah, i know it's deprecated but it is still supported by all browsers...